# Does ResultSet.updateRow() commit, i.e. end the transaction?

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, commit

According to the documentation `ResultSet.updateRow()` [Updates the underlying database with the new contents of the current row of this ResultSet object.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateRow())

Will this perform a commit, i.e. end the current transaction?

Comment: That method should update the database like an update query does, i.e. if the database and connection aren't set to auto-commit the transaction should still be alive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If auto-commit is disabled, then only explicitly calling `Connection.commit()` will commit a transaction. So, with auto-commit disabled, updating a result set row will not commit.

When auto-commit mode is enabled different rules apply. The [JDBC 4.3 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html), section 10.1 *Transaction Boundaries and Auto-commit* says:

> The `Connection` attribute auto-commit specifies when to end
>   transactions. Enabling auto-commit causes a transaction commit after
>   each individual SQL statement as soon as that statement is complete.
>   The point at which a statement is considered to be “complete” depends
>   on the type of SQL statement as well as what the application does
>   after executing it:
>
> - For Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements such as Insert, Update, Delete, and DDL statements, the statement is complete as soon
>     as it has finished executing.
> - For `Select` statements, the statement is complete when the associated result set is closed.
> - For `CallableStatement` objects or for statements that return multiple results, the statement is complete when all of the associated
>     result sets have been closed, and all update counts and output
>     parameters have been retrieved.

As updating a row in a result set does not close the result set, it doesn't complete the statement, and therefor it should **not** trigger a commit. So, based on the JDBC standard, updating a row in a result set in auto-commit mode should not commit until the result set is closed.

However, it is entirely possible that actual implementations do not adhere to this rule. For example, because the driver uses `UPDATE` statements to effect the change and the driver uses server-side auto-commit logic which will automatically commit once that `UPDATE` statement ends. Also, given the rules I quoted are a bit ambiguous, a driver could also interpret the rules that the update of a row is a DML update, and therefor should trigger a commit.

In other words, auto-commit mode and updatable result sets might behave differently between different JDBC drivers. I would recommend that when you want to use updatable result sets, that you disable auto-commit mode so your code is in control of the transaction boundary by calling `Connection.commit()` explicitly.

As an aside, using updatable result sets is almost always the wrong tool. Consider carefully if you really need to use them. They only really make sense in interactive user applications, and even then you should consider alternatives.